# Hosting Thin Clients on RHEL 5.5 / Cent OS 5.5

Tags: centos, redhat, pxe-boot, thin-client

I have DHCP, TFTP in place which lets users install Cent OS 5.5 when they boot from network from there machines.

I want that they should be able to boot Cent OS right away and log into there accounts. What should be I doing for that? I need to do this because we have new HP diskless thin clients. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.ltsp.org/ i think i found something like that there in the past.
You will need a central nfs server for full featured Centos Desktop